# Phantom types used for tracking units (time, distance) in Haskell, how can this code be improved (made more readable, expressive, shorter) ?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I am very new to phantom types and GADTs. I wonder if this code could could be improved using type families ?

I suspect that it could because I have heard that dependent typing is often implemented using type families in Haskell and in some sense this code shows a very simple usage of dependent types in the `getSpeed` function. In that function the type of result depends on the type of the inputs (in a very trivial way).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs,StandaloneDeriving #-}
main=do
 let t=Time 1 Hour
 let d=Distance 1 Meter
 putStrLn $ show $ getSpeed d t

class (Show u) =>DistanceUnit u

data KiloMeter=KiloMeter deriving Show
data Meter= Meter deriving Show

instance DistanceUnit Meter
instance DistanceUnit KiloMeter

class (Show u) =>TimeUnit u

data Second = Second deriving Show
data Hour = Hour deriving Show

instance TimeUnit Second
instance TimeUnit Hour

data Distance u where
  Distance:: (DistanceUnit u) => Double -> u->Distance u

data Time u where
  Time:: (TimeUnit u) => Double -> u-> Time u

deriving instance Show (Distance u)
deriving instance Show (Time t)

data Speed du tu where
  Speed::(DistanceUnit du, TimeUnit tu)=> Double -> du->tu->Speed du tu

deriving instance Show (Speed du tu)

getSpeed:: Distance du-> Time tu ->Speed du tu
getSpeed (Distance  dv du) (Time tv tu)=Speed (dv/tv) du tu

getSpeedUnitAsString::Speed du tu ->String
getSpeedUnitAsString (Speed v du tu)=show du++"/"++ show tu
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dimensional (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) and Units (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/units) packages? There is also the Dimensional Type Families package (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-tf), but that is deprecated in favour of plain Dimensional.

Comment: No, I am not, thanks for the tip!

Comment: See also https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uom-plugin-0.1.1.0/docs/Data-UnitsOfMeasure-Tutorial.html

Comment: @haoformayor : interesting, thanks !